# Statistical test to examine multiple attributes' effect on an outcome

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I want to compare different attributes of a population and see if one is more indicative of an outcome measurement than the other.

In a general case, suppose I want to examine $k$ attributes. Each attribute is binary, meaning that each individual either has this attribute or doesn't. At the first time point, I sample a large number $n$ (>1 million) from the whole population and obtain outcome measurement values, $v_{1,1}$ ...$v_{1,n}$. I also obtain all attributes for each individual. At the second time point, I sample another large number $m$ (>1 million) from the whole population and obtain outcome measurement values, $v_{2,1}$ ...$v_{2,m}$. I again obtain all attributes for each individual. Let's assume the the population is so large that I don't have any overlap in the members that I sample at two different time points. I want to see if one attribute is more indicative of changes in the outcome measurement between two time points, and perform a suitable statistical test.

Here is an example:

At the first time point, I sampled a large group of people at age 15 and measured their height. I recorded if each one of them 1) eats meat or 2) eats fruit or 3) eats vegetable. Let's assume no one in the whole population changes diet ever. After a year, I sampled another large group of people at age 16 (not the same people as those a year ago) and measured their height. I also recorded if each one of them 1) eats meat or 2) eats fruit or 3) eats vegetable. So I want to see if eating meat is more helpful than eating fruit or eating vegetable in gaining height.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what kind of statistical test I should use here?

Thank you!

Comment: the Cross Validated stack exchange site might be more apt for this question

Comment: Thanks. I re-posted there.

Comment: Is it not hard to make any statements unless one has access to the same set of people? ie you want to control for all other variables. (ref: Randomized Control Trials)? So 1) it is hard to rule out the fact that some subset you took at 16 is randomly taller than the subset you took when they were 15. 2) It is hard to rule out some other variable causing both meat eating and taller height (say genetics)

Comment: What if my sample size is large? And also, I don't need to examine the causality. I think correlation is good enough.